# Find a string in xml tag and delete a line which is part of match tag

Tags: sed, xml

Need to search a string `<oneFi institution="12345678">` and need to delete only the `<value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/>`

Actual:

```
      <oneFi institution="12345678">
        <bin _list="1">
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/>
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="544448"/>
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="557231"/>
        </bin>
      </oneFi>
      <oneFi institution="854784662">
        <bin _list="1">
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/>
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="544448"/>
        </bin>
      </oneFi>
```

Expected:

```
      <oneFi institution="12345678">
        <bin _list="1">
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="544448"/>
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="557231"/>
        </bin>
      </oneFi>
      <oneFi institution="854784662">
        <bin _list="1">
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/>
          <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="544448"/>
        </bin>
      </oneFi>
```

Comment: It is completely unclear what you're asking. Please post an example of your input aswell as the expected output, otherwise we won't be able to help you. You should also include in your question what you have tried on your own, and the problems you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the XML document is valid, for example like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <oneFi institution="12345678">
    <bin _list="1">
      <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/>
      <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="544448"/>
      <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="557231"/>
    </bin>
  </oneFi>
  <oneFi institution="854784662">
    <bin _list="1">
      <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/>
      <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="544448"/>
    </bin>
  </oneFi>
</root>
```

(your example lacks a root node)

Then you may use XMLstarlet:

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -d '//oneFi[@institution="12345678"]//value[@prefix="528749"]' file.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <oneFi institution="12345678">
    <bin _list="1">
      <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="544448"/>
      <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="557231"/>
    </bin>
  </oneFi>
  <oneFi institution="854784662">
    <bin _list="1">
      <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"/>
      <value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="544448"/>
    </bin>
  </oneFi>
</root>
```

The XPATH expression `//oneFi[@institution="12345678"]//value[@prefix="528749"]` will match the node that you mention in the question using the  `institution` attribute of the `oneFi` node and the `prefix` attribute of the `value` node somewhere under the selected `oneFi` node.

Would you need to be more specific about the values of the `value` node's attributes, then you may match the other attributes too using

```
value[@prefix="528749" and @maxPAN="19" and @minPAN="4"]
```

in that part of the expression.

The `ed -d` (or `ed --delete`) bit of the XMLstarlet command means the utility is supposed to *edit* the XML document and *delete* the nodes matching the expression.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not possible to manipulate XML with tools like `sed`, `awk` or `grep`. For general XML use an XML parsing library.

If your XML file is always formatted in the same way, i.e. one tag per line, same nesting of tags as in your example, it would be possible with `awk`.

```
awk  'BEGIN { institutionMatch=0; skipValue=0; }
/<oneFi institution="[^"]*">/ { institutionMatch=0; }      # assume other institution
/<oneFi institution="12345678">/ { institutionMatch=1; }   # relevant institution
/<value maxPAN="19" minPAN="4" prefix="528749"\/>/ { if(institutionMatch)
    skipValue=1;   # mark to skip if found in matching institution
}
{ if(!skipValue) { print; } skipValue=0; }' inputfile > outputfile
```

Note: This script may produce garbage if your XML file looks different from your example.